# "Session has expired" message with Machine Learning Studio

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am getting consistent error "Your session has expired" (screenshot below), after logging in to machine learning studio.

I have tried chrome incognito and guest windows, but no difference.

I am using a new account and have signed up for Free workspace. Any suggestion to get past this or delete workspace, to start again?

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: @JoyWang - I will try this later today and update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, I sign out and log in https://studio.azureml.net/ again, it solved my problem. Or you can try to clear the browsing data or change a browser. Anyway, the issue should be caused by the browser, not azure. Even if your account is not the owner of the workspace, when you click `Sign In` in https://studio.azureml.net/ , it will create a free workspace(with a different workspace id) for you automatically.

[image]

If you want to delete the workspace, you need to let the owner of the workspace delete it, navigate to the `SETTINGS` on the left of the studio -> `NAME` -> `DELETE WORKSPACE`.

[image]

Comment: Joy, thank you for the answer and I apologize that it took me forever to come back to this.As issue was related to chrome - I tried clearing browser session, incognito and guest window. I kept getting same issue. I end up trying this in MS Edge and site seems to be working fine without any issues. Issue is related to browser for me - not related to browser cache. Thanks for your help.